# How to index tibble in tidyverse setNames()

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to take a value of a cell in a tibble and use that in renaming a column.

For example, suppose in the `mtcars` dataframe, I want to concatenate the value in the first row of the `mpg` column to the column name of the `disp` column.

My initial thought would be something like:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, cyl, disp) %>% 
  setNames(c('miles', 'cylinders', paste0('disp_', mpg[1])))
```

However, that doesn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you can only infer columns from a data frame with certain `dplyr` verbs such as `mutate`, `summarize`, `group_by` etc (or if you use the `with` keyword). `setNames` is a base R function that's not in this list, so you will need to explicitly specify the data frame from which `mpg` comes from; Since you are using pipe `%>%`, you can use `.$mpg` to refer the column:

```
mtcars %>% 
    select(mpg, cyl, disp) %>% 
    setNames(c('miles', 'cylinders', paste0('disp_', .$mpg[1])))

#                    miles cylinders disp_21
#Mazda RX4            21.0         6   160.0
# ...
```